# Creating a Mongoose plugin that supports callbacks AND promises

Tags: node.js, mongoose, bluebird, es6-promise, mongoose-plugins

I have a Mongoose plugin that currently only supports callbacks, I plan on possibly publishing it to npmjs, but I first wanted to make sure that it works just like the existing Mongoose functions/methods, which support callbacks and [some built in promises](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html), and you can also [specify your own promise library](http://eddywashere.com/blog/switching-out-callbacks-with-promises-in-mongoose/).

I wanted to know what the best way was to implement the same functionality in my library, meaning how can I support both callbacks **and** promises? I found [a similar SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23501146/creating-node-library-that-support-both-node-callbacks-and-promise-with-bluebird), but thats specific to bluebird, which even though I like to use, Id like to not assume it will be used. (Also, that article looks like it might be out-dated, as I couldnt find `nodeify` in the [bluebird api docs](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html)

I was thinking I could just do some basic logic to see if a function was provided as one of the parameters, if so, then execute the callback, if not, then return a promise... but im sure theres an easier way to do that.

Also, for the Promises, when I *do* return a promise, should I use the `Promise` thats inside the `Mongoose` object thats handed to the plugins? Meaning:

```js
module.exports = Mongoose => {
    // Just verifying, should I use this?..
    const Promise = Mongoose.Promise

    return Mongoose.model( 'Foobar', new Mongoose.Schema({ /* ... */ }) )
}
```

### Update

Regarding the last question, about what Promise object to reference when returning promises, I tried using the `Mongoose.Promise` as stated above, code below:

```js
module.exports = Mongoose => {
    const Promise = Mongoose.Promise
    const Schema = Mongoose.Schema

    const fooSchema = new Schema({
        name: Schema.Types.String
    })

    fooSchema.statics.blah = function( ) {
        // Return Mongoose.Promise
        return new Promise( ( res, rej ) => {
            res( 'test' )
        })
    }

    return Mongoose.model( 'Foobar', fooSchema )
}
```

... Which resulted in the error:

```
/Users/me/project/node_modules/mongoose/lib/ES6Promise.js:21
  throw 'Can\'t use ES6 promise with mpromise style constructor';
  ^
Can't use ES6 promise with mpromise style constructor
```

So I'm guessing thats not the right way to go... I thought it would be a better idea to return promises using the same promise library Mongoose has configured (Custom, or default..)

I tried to see how Mongoose does it by looking at the [findOne](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/query.js#L1139-L1178) function code, but I dont quite see how it returns a promise if theres no callback specified
**P.S.** Im using Mongoose *4.3.7*

### Update

Was just tinkering around, but would this be an acceptable method? Or is it bad practice

```js
function tester(foo, cb){
    return new Promise( ( res, rej ) => {
        const result = 'You said ' + foo
        if( typeof cb === 'function' ){
            cb( null, result )
            res() // Is this needed?
        }
        else {
            res( result )
        }
    })
}

tester('foo', (err, data) => {
    if( err )
        console.log('ERROR!',err)
    else
        console.log('Result:',data)
})

tester('bar')
    .then( data => {
        console.log('Result:',data)
    })
    .catch( err => {
        console.log('ERROR!',err)
    })
```

Comment: I'm not sure why are you even trying to create a mongoose plugin... mangoose already support plugins doesn't it... Why does it need a plugin..? Are you going to create something like mongoose but not mongoose..?!

Comment: Im trying to create a **mongoose plugin**... You think im trying to create a plugin system or something?.. Im just asking how can I create a mongoose plugin, that supports both callbacks **and** promises, like Mongoose itself does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I mainly didn't want to rely on a specific promise library, incase they were using a different one, but I realized that for the most part, it shouldnt really matter. So I decided to stick with Bluebird, and use the *[asCallback](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/ascallback.html)* method

Heres the end result, this is with me coding a library with a function that supports both callbacks and promises; and in a *separate* file, and without requiring a specific promise library, using that function twice, once with a promise, and once with a callback:

```js
// ./test-lib.js
'use strict'

const Promise = require( 'bluebird' )

module.exports = ( str, cb ) => {
    const endResult = ( txt ) => new Promise( ( res, rej ) => res( 'You said ' + txt ) )
    return endResult( str ).asCallback( cb );
}

// app.js
'use strict'

const Testlib = require('./test-lib')

Testlib('foo', ( err, data ) => {
    if( err )
        console.error('ERROR:',err)
    else
        console.log('DATA:',data)
})

Testlib('bar')
    .then( data => {
        console.log('DATA:',data)
    })
    .catch( err => {
        console.error('ERROR:',err)
    })

// Result:
// DATA: You said foo
// DATA: You said bar
```

That seems to have worked perfectly! (Thanks to [tyscorp](https://github.com/tyscorp) the Bluebird Gitter chat)

Answer (score 0):

just do this

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise
```

as simple as that